# Replace class methods with lambda expressions, is it bad practice?

Tags: java, class, lambda, functional-interface

I had a few questions that I'm having trouble finding the answer to, at least in Java.

I saw a Class definition in a tutorial where lambdas were being used similar to methods. So I'm curious as to if there is any benefit apart from concise code and style preference.

Example:

```
public class Blocks {
    private Deque<Block> entries;

    public Blocks() {
        this.entries = new ArrayDeque<>();
    }

    public Deque<Block> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public void setEntries(Deque<Block> entries) {
        this.entries = new ArrayDeque<>(entries);
    }

    public Predicate<Block> push = entries::offerLast;

    public Supplier<Optional<Block>> peek = () -> Optional.ofNullable(entries.peekLast());

    public BooleanSupplier isEmpty = entries::isEmpty;

    public Supplier<String> lastHash = () -> peek.get().map(Block::hash).orElse("0");

    public LongSupplier size = entries::size;
}
```

Is this a valid class definition? Is this a bad practice? If so, why?

One thing I noticed is that in the Predicate push, I get the following warning:

```
Dereference of 'entries' will produce 'NullPointerException'
```

Why am I getting this warning if entries should be instantiated? The warning seems to affect any function with a method reference. If instead:

```
public Predicate<Block> push = block -> entries.offerLast(block);
```

then the warning disappears.

Comment: It's valid code but very awkward to handle and I doubt that it's any improvement to conciseness. To actually push something into the deque you'd have to call `push.test(block);` instead of just `push(block)` if you'd defined that as a "regular" method instead. Code like this becomes confusing pretty fast. The other variables have the same issue, so I'd say it's bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. The push doesn't really bother me much because it returns a boolean. So, push.test kind of makes sense in that way. But yea, I definitely agree with you, it is awkward. Any idea why the functions with the method references give that warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field initialisers of a class run in textual order, before the constructor. Therefore, the fields `push`, `isEmpty` etc are going to be initialised before `entries` gets initialised in the constructor.

When a method reference expression such as `entries::offerLast` is evaluated, `entries` is evaluated first to determine on which object should the method be called. However, since `entries` is not initialised at the time when the method reference expression is evaluated, `entries` evaluates to null. This causes a `NullPointerException` to be thrown. [JLS 15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3)

> First, if the method reference expression begins with an ExpressionName or a Primary, this subexpression is evaluated. If the subexpression evaluates to null, a NullPointerException is raised, and the method reference expression completes abruptly.

To fix this, you can either move the initialisation of the `entires` field out of the constructor, and inline with its declaration:

```
private Deque<Block> entries = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

Or, you can use a lambda expression instead of a method reference:

```
public Predicate<Block> push = e -> entries.offerLast(e);
```

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. Is it bad practice to write classes like this? Or is it just a style preference?

Comment: @essentialz I would say that yes it is a bad practice, and no, this is not a style preference. Java is not designed to be written this way. This breaks the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), at least.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering all my questions. I will definitely avoid using functions this way. I appreciate the help.